# VB How to play audio file

Tags: vb.net, audio-player

I am trying to play a sound once a button is clicked with this code I found everywhere on the internet:

```
Private Sub but_play_sound_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles but_play_sound.Click
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.fileName1, AudioPlayMode.Background)
End Sub 'fileName1 being the audio file
```

But visual studio comes up with these 3 errors and I am stumped.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BC30456 'Computer' is not a member of 'Soundbank.My'.   Soundbank   C:\Users\nick_\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Soundbank\Soundbank\MainPage.xaml.vb  10  Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BC30456 'Resources' is not a member of 'Soundbank.My'.  Soundbank   C:\Users\nick_\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Soundbank\Soundbank\MainPage.xaml.vb  10  Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BC30451 'AudioPlayMode' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.    Soundbank   C:\Users\nick_\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Soundbank\Soundbank\MainPage.xaml.vb  10  Active

I should also add I would like to store my audio files in another folder inside the assets folder.

Comment: Shouldn't `My` be `Me`?

Answer (score 0):

in VB projects, `My` refers to a special namespace that contains objects that provide shortcuts for common tasks, for example `My.Computer`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11bxex12.aspx

It is not to be confused with `Me`, `My`, `MyBase` and `MyClass` which are all  described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20fy88e0.aspx

The compiler seems to be saying that the standalone identifier `My` is now referring to `Soundbank.My` - which I assume is some member in your class or project (as `Soundbank` is not a type-name in the CLR or Base Class Library).

So use `Ctrl+,` to find out where `My` is being redefined and change it so `My` no-longer refers to something in your project.

Comment: Soundbank is the project name and the code snippet I included below is all of the code I have for my project.

`Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
    Inherits Page

 Private Sub but_play_sound_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles but_play_sound.Click
  Me.Computer.Audio.Play(Me.Resources.fileName1, AudioPlayMode.Background)
 End Sub
End Class`

I don't see where `my` would be defined...

Comment: @Nick Your code references objects in a XAML file, so there **is** more to your project than just that VB code. Please post your XAML.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. the snippet was too long for a comment, hope you don't mind, I pasted it as a gist. gist.github.com/nstjlol/edd4e35b4d14e1851c5d146c832896e0

Comment: @Nick You can put your code in your question. Edit it.